# Trouble adding BottomBar to Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to add BottomBar (3rd party lib) to my android studio project as a module.  I get the error Error: (4, 0) Cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist and it's pointing to build.gradle file.  I'm not sure what's wrong.  Appreciate any help.

BottomBar:
https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/master/README.md#common-problems-and-solutions

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bottombar.sample"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':bottom-bar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion
compile 'com.android.support:design:' + rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion

testCompile 'junit:junit:' + rootProject.ext.junitVersion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget it, I figured it out.  I don't need to import it as a module, just add it as a dependency.

Comment: I got `Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0` error, when add it as dependency.